# DHCP server over internal adapter VirtualBox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dhcp

I am trying to create simple network between two VM in VirtualBox using **Internal Adapter** and **isc-dhcp-server**. Both VM's are connected with **intnet** network adapter, and the main one has installed and configured **isc-dhcp-server**. The second one has configured to receive network address with dhcp . But in the **ping** from dhcp client is not received by dhcp server. And I have no idea what caused such an issue. Could you please help me to troubleshoot this. Below is configuration files from server/client sides.

Client /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

Server /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
option domain-name "gw-serv.org";
option domain-name-servers 172.16.3.1;
default-lease-time 3600;
max-lease-time 7200;
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 172.16.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option routers 172.16.3.1;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    range 172.16.3.2 172.16.3.254;
}
```

/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server:

```
INTERFACESv4="enp0s9"
```

Network interfaces on dhcp server + nmap scan of dhcp IPs
[image: network interfaces on dhcp server + nmap scan of dhcp IPs]

Network interfaces on dhcp client
[image: network interfaces on dhcp client]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there was no problem with **isc-dhcp-server** configuration files, the problem was in wrong order of *Host-only adapter* and *Internal adapter*. After changing enp0s8 to enp0s9 and enp0s9 to enp0s8 everything started to work just fine.

The solution was found due to switching off adapters from VirtualBox GUI, and testing server **ifconfig** output.